# Finding fundamental frequency .wav file Matlab

Tags: matlab, frequency

I have to extract the fundamental frequency from a .wav file of 1 second long.

I have looked over several options like finding the peaks or doing a complex cepstrum but no luck so far. I have read over the last couple of weeks a lot about it but still i cannot find a viable and optimal way of doing it. I am new to Matlab and Signal Processing.

```
filedir = dir('*.wav');  

[y, Fs] = audioread(filedir.name);
x = y(y ~= 0) % removing the zeroes from the array
psdest = psd(spectrum.periodogram,x,'Fs',Fs,'NFFT',length(x));
[~,I] = max(psdest.Data);
fprintf('Maximum occurs at %d Hz.\n',psdest.Frequencies(I));
```

The output is for example: Maximum occurs at 5.758645e+02 Hz

I will probably need to actually transform that number into Hz.

For the complex cepstrum:

```
load mtlb

dt = 1/Fs;
I0 = round(0.1/dt);
Iend = round(1/dt);
x = mtlb(I0:Iend);

c = cceps(x);


t = 0:dt:length(x)*dt-dt;

trng = t(t>=2e-3 & t<=10e-3);
crng = c(t>=2e-3 & t<=10e-3);

[~,I] = max(crng);

fprintf('Complex cepstrum F0 estimate is %3.2f Hz.\n',1/trng(I))
clearvars
```

The output values is the same for all the files I load so clearly something is wrong.

I have been struggling for a while and I really need to figure this out. To extract that fundamental frequency. I use Matlab 2016b.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried the first part with various `.wav` files and it seems to work. It returns the correct value in Hz.

Comment: The second part seems ok to me too... what files did you load, are the outputs **exactly** the same? With a time range between 2 and 10 ms, you will find a frequency between 100 and 500 Hz.